# Вставка данных в несколько связанных таблиц одновременно

Tags: mysql, sql

Хотел бы поинтересоваться, как добавлять данные в связанные таблицы одним запросом.  На рисунке изображена схема БД.  Как добавить автора и книгу так, чтобы их ИД добавилось в центральную таблицу? БД на *MySQL*.

[image: Database Schema]

Comment: Сразу вопрос: почему не использовать транзакции?  И какая СУБД?

Comment: Три запроса INSERT в три таблицы. Но тут всё зависит от  того, какие ключи в таблицах authors и books. Если они автогенерируемые в БД, то после вставки нужно их получить для вставки в третью таблицу.

Comment: И к вопросам выше - а что является источником данных? Это потоковоя подача данных извне, или другая таблица этой же базы? Откуда (из какой исполняемой среды) вы хотите запускать данные запросы - это программа на языке программирования или хранимый запрос в СУБД?

Comment: @Ainar-G, прошу прощения, указал.

Comment: @cauf, микросервис на node.js

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ключи чисто auto_increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Принял решение использовать транзакции, как посоветовали выше.
вот пример, может кому-то поможет

```
START TRANSACTION;

SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;

INSERT INTO authors(author_name) VALUE ('Vern');
SET @a = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO books(title) VALUE ('Captain');
SET @b = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO books_data(author_id, book_id) VALUES (@a, @b);

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2):

1 запросом никак не выйдет.

Сначала делаете вставку в authors и books, а потом в book_authors.

Т.е получается 3 запроса.

А если у вас authors и books имеют ID, которые генерируются(Identity), то вам их понадобится получить, а это еще +2 запроса.

Конечно, можно сделать какие-нибудь хитрые триггеры для заполнения центральной таблицы, но это по моему уже извращение+ вы просто скрываете дополнительные запросы, которые на самом деле есть.

Это я пишу по опыту использования MS SQL, так как не указана конкретная СУБД, но в других СУБД я такого не встречал.

Да, если говорить в разрезе ORM под СУБД, например Entity Framework, то он автоматически заполняет центральную таблицу, но он все равно за "кулисами" вызывает запрос на вставку.

Comment: Ключи просто auto increment. Спасибо за ответ, а есть где-нибудь пример такого запроса?

Comment: Вон сверху пример привели. В MS SQL можно через OUTPUT получить вставленные значения, а там получить уже реальное значение IDENTITY.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не указали СУБД!  В *PostgreSQL*, благодаря нестандартному
расширению `RETURNING`, можно сделать так:

```sql
WITH new_authors(id) AS (
  INSERT INTO authors
    (         name)
  VALUES
    ('Ivan Ivanov')
  RETURNING id
)
, new_books(id) AS (
  INSERT INTO books
    (         title)
  VALUES
    ('Ivan''s Book')
  RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO book_authors (author_id, book_id)
SELECT new_authors.id, new_books.id
  FROM new_authors CROSS JOIN new_books
;

SELECT * FROM book_authors;
```

В других СУБД, где этого или подобного расширения нет, скорее всего
нельзя.

Comment: Большое спасибо, да забыл указать. Бд на простом mysql

Comment: @Glechik  Тогда, наверное, только транзакции.